# Python why is file path considered a directory

Tags: python, path, directory, delete-file

I am working on a Django project where I want to replace a file on my server. One way of doing it is to remove the file if the filename already exists and saving the new file at its place.

My problem is that my file path that ends with /data.xlsx is considered a directory. In python, os.isfile(path) returns false and os.isdir(path) returns true, though the path is this:

```
path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name)).replace('\\', '/')
```

which returns something like

```
"G:/username/path/to/django/project/static/data/data.xlsx"
```

os.remove(path) returns an OSError because path is not a file path supposedly. And I checked and I have all permissions on this file (0777).

I don't know how to make python understand that this is an Excel file and not a directory. Can someone help me? I don't have any debugging ideas left.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A path name does not define whether something is a file or directory. You could name a file `"/tmp/my/directory"` and a directory  `"/tmp/my/file.xls"` if you felt like it. Likewise, python doesn't *decide* whether a path corresponds to a file or a directory, it only checks. If python says the file corresponds to a directory, that means your OS says it's a directory. Either your OS is seriously messed up, or you actually have a directory named `path`.

Hint: It's likely the later. Try removing the directory at `path`.

Comment: Ok, so me code probably created a sort of empty directory called data.xlsx (highly probably since I tried a millions things in the past days), and when I called shutil.rmtree(path) it removed it, and now os.remove(path) does not cause any error. And thanks for the answer btw, I did not realise we could name a folder with an extension. I hoped it was not my OS that was messed up since it is very new haha!